# How to set active list style when carousel move automatically?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to change list still when it is in active. My carousel will move automatically at certain timing by default, When it moves the corresponding list `class` should be `active`and that color should change automatically.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/blue.jpg">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/purple.jpg">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/red.jpg">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1694x1131/777">
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            
            </div>
                    
            <div class="carousel-buttons">
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center" style="background-color:orange;height:50px; padding:10px;"><a class="active" data-target="#myCarousel"  data-slide-to="0" href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a></div>
            
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center" style="background-color:orange;height:50px; padding:10px;"><a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" href="#">TRADING</a></div>
            
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center" style="background-color:orange;height:50px; padding:10px;"><a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" href="#">CONTRACTING</a></div>
            
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center" style="background-color:orange;height:50px; padding:10px;"><a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" href="#">TRAFFIC</a></div>
            </div>    
            
        </div>
        

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Output]
First picture is Technology, 2. Trading, 3. Contracting, 4. Traffic

when carousel move it's not set automatically `class="active"`.

those link should work like carousel-indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class="carousel-indicators" instead of class="carousel-buttons". So "active" will change automatically.